# ListView adapter LinkedList<class>

Tags: listview, linked-list, adapter

i have a problem with my code.
I have a class:

```
    public static class Categoria{
    int ID;
    String descr;
}
```

And a linked list of this class:

```
List<Categoria> Categorie=new LinkedList<Categoria>();
```

I need to create a ListView that contains only the values of field "descr" of my list.

How can i do it?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Solved by using getView method.